# How to make Vim LaTeX Suite show errors when compile

Tags: errors, compiling, vim

Compiling TeX with command

```
: silent call Tex_RunLaTeX()
```

The `gvim` window turns grey when there are errors. One needs to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for each error to continue.

It will be better if the error messages show up in the process as in the console output. Can I configure the latex-suite to achieve that?

Comment: Or can I make Compiling aborted when error exists. It is enough to enter dozens times when compile new docx.

Answer (score 1):

Use in your `.vimrc` something like

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
```

You can compile by typing `\ll` in normal mode, which is much faster than using the command mode.